# JQuery Image Picker is not working

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

I am trying to develop an Image Picker following these tutorials `http://jsfiddle.net/huanlin/mgvrc/` and `http://rvera.github.io/image-picker/#`

Here is the code I have tried so far

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Try Image Picker</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="image-picker.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
  <script type="text/javascript" src="image-picker.js"/> </script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="image-picker.min.js"/> </script>
  <script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
      $("#selectImage").imagepicker({
        hide_select: true
      });

      var $container = $('.image_picker_selector');
      // initialize
        $container.imagesLoaded(function () {
          $container.masonry({
            columnWidth: 30,
            itemSelector: '.thumbnail'
          });
        });
    });

  function myFunction() {
      document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Paragraph changed.";
  }
  </script>
</head>

<body>
    <select id="selectImage" class="image-picker">
        <option value=""></option>
        <option data-img-src="o.png" value="1">  Image 1  </option>
        <option data-img-src="aa.png" value="2">  Image 2  </option>
        <option data-img-src="ee.png" value="3">  Image 3  </option>
    </select>
<br>
<p id="demo">A Paragraph</p>

<button type="button" onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

</body>
</html>
```

But no image is showing in the browser. All CSS, JS scripts and images have been linked properly. Can you suggest what am I doing wrong here?

Comment: You didn't include masonry library and imagesLoaded plugin.

Comment: How can I do so? Can you give me a little more detail?

Comment: You can include masonry using this code `<script src="https://npmcdn.com/masonry-layout@4.0/dist/masonry.pkgd.min.js"></script>` and imagesLoaded using this `<script src="https://npmcdn.com/imagesloaded@4.1/imagesloaded.pkgd.min.js"></script>`

Comment: Just done that. Still no change :(

Answer (score 0):

This is jQuery plugin. I see it's missing in your html head.

Comment: I have included image-picker.css, image-picker.js & image-picker.min.js in the html head. Aren't these links enough to do so? Or I need to do something else to enable JQuery plugin?

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/11189650)

Comment: @SudipPodder It does seem that you need to include the jQuery library. See [How jQuery Works](http://learn.jquery.com/about-jquery/how-jquery-works/). You also seem to have included the "image-picker" plugin twice.

Comment: @Magicprog.fr This actually is an attempted answer pointing out that the jQuery plugin being referenced may not be included correctly. This should not have been flagged, and should not be recommended for deletion in the LQPRQ. See: [You're doing it wrong: A plea for sanity in the Low Quality Posts queue](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/287563) and [Your answer is in another castle: when is an answer not an answer?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/225370)